# Remove Fragment from backstack with Navigation components

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have a PinCreateActivity with a navHost fragment with 2 Fragments PinSetup and PinCreate fragments.

When the Activity launches, the PinSetup is the default fragment and after that with a click button i navigate to the PinCreate fragment. What i want is from the PinCreate fragment, when the User clicks the back button NOT to go to the PinSetup and navigate to the backstack as would the PinCreateActivity would do. So i guess when i navigate from the PinSetup to the PinCreate fragment i have to remove the PinSetup from the backStack. How can i do that?

navigation_graph.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pin_create_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/pinSetupFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/pinSetupFragment"
        android:name="com.example.ui.fragments.pin.PinSetupFragment"
        android:label="Create PIN"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_pin_setup" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_pinSetupFragment_to_pinCreateFragment"
            app:destination="@id/pinCreateFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/pinCreateFragment"
        android:name="com.example.ui.fragments.pin.PinCreateFragment"
        android:label="Your PIN"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_pin_create" />
</navigation>
```

PinCreateActivity

```
private lateinit var navController: NavController

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 
    ...
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.pin_create_host_fragment)


    // onClick
    navController.navigate(R.id.action_pinSetupFragment_to_pinCreateFragment)

 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that programmatically from Kotlin code if you need some extra logic while doing pop up.
But if you just need to remove `PinSetupFragment` from your back stack, you can do that on your navigation graph xml file.

So, if you are just going to pop up your fragment without any other extra logic, best way to pop up `PinSetupFragment` from your back stack would be updating your `navigation_graph.xml` file.

Just add these two lines to your action:

```xml
app:popUpTo="@id/pinSetupFragment"
app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

As a result, your `navigation_graph.xml` file will be like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pin_create_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/pinSetupFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/pinSetupFragment"
        android:name="com.example.ui.fragments.pin.PinSetupFragment"
        android:label="Create PIN"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_pin_setup" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_pinSetupFragment_to_pinCreateFragment"
            app:destination="@id/pinCreateFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/pinSetupFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/pinCreateFragment"
        android:name="com.example.ui.fragments.pin.PinCreateFragment"
        android:label="Your PIN"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_pin_create" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: Well that works, however i added 'app:popUpTo="@+id/pin_create_nav_graph"' and it has the same effect. Thank you anyway

Comment: Yes, you are right, this can do same because you have two fragments. But this is making pop up for all the previous fragments inside this nav_graph.
So, if you just need to pop up one fragment and have 3 or more fragments, you should use the id of the fragment that you want to pop up.

Comment: Ohhh...ok!! I dint know that! Thank you

Comment: This was very helpful in my case where my app opened dashboardFragment from splashFragment. The properties `popUpTo="@id/splashFragment` and `popUpToInclusive=true` worked! However, I am still curious about the details. what just Android do behind the scenes?